# Low graphics error, asking for some command to fix it

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, live-usb, live-environment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

When I run Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 from USB in safe mode it shows an error that says the system is running in low graphics mode. When I click to reconfigure low graphics mode it prompts for some command. What should I do? I am a complete beginner on the Linux platform. Should I install it without fixing the graphics, or should I solve the graphics problem before installing?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this problem after your installation.  If you are connected to the internet when you perform your install you will get all updated packages.

Once you boot into Ubuntu you can go to system settings and then click additional drivers this works most of the time with video cards.

If you post your video card model we can look and see if it will work with Ubuntu.